# How to issue a warning/error message to the user if coupon has already been redeemed using PHP contact with SQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've put together a codebase that successfully calls Ajax to a PHP server which issues requests to a database. I'm very new to this, but I've been able to successfully update rows in the SQL.

The good news is it doesn't update that row if there are already values in email, name, and redeem time columns. How do I cause the program to make errors if the coupon code has already been redeemed, though?

Is using a test query a possible approach? Or should I try to set up a separate Ajax request..possibly a Get to do a comparative evaluation on submission with the values in the form? But even if that is the case I have no idea how to actually implement that sort of conditional  in PHP. Thanks if you have any advice.

```
//user_process.php

  <?php
      $con = mysqli_connect(); //<--redacted ;D 
      //first, test with what should be in the db 
      //with defaults. 
        $testcode=$_GET["code"];
        $testname="Unredeemed";
        $testemail="N/a";
        $testredeemed="0000/00/00 00:00:00";

        $testquery=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT code,name,email,redeemed FROM codestore WHERE code='$testcode', name='$testname', email='$email', redeemed='$testredeemed'");

        if($testcode){
        if(!$testquery){
          die("Er");
        }
        }

      $code=$_POST["code"];
      $name=$_POST["name"];
      $email=$_POST["email"];
      $redeemed=$_POST["redeemed"];

     $query=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE codestore SET name='$name', email='$email', redeemed='$redeemed' WHERE code='$code',name='Unredeemed',email='N/a',redeemed='0000/00/00 00:00:00'");

      if($query){
    echo "Your comment has been sent";
      }
      else{
    echo "Error in sending your comment";
      }

    ?>

//user_index.js
    function formatDate(date) {
        //deleted for readability  
    }

    $("#submit").click(function (event) {
        $(".main-content").append("<?php require 'user_process.php';?>  ");
    //  if() each has a value else alert error 
    var currentDateTime = new Date();
    var redeemedOn = formatDate(currentDateTime);
    var code = $("#code").val(); 
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post"
            , url: "user_process.php"
            , data: "code=" + code + "&name="+name+"&email="+email+"&redeemed="+redeemedOn
            , success: function (data) {
                $("#info").html(data);
            }
            , error: function(){
                alert("That code is invalid or has already been redeemed!")
            }
        });
    });

//index.php
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/demo_mini.css">
        <title>Search Contacts</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            <form class="form-basic">
                <div class="form-row"> <span>Enter your code </span>
                    <input type="text" name="code" id="code"> </div>
                <div class="form-row"> <span>Full Name </span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"> </div>
                <div class="form-row"> <span>Email</span>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <button id="submit">Redeem!</button>
                </div>
                <div id="info" /> </form>
        </div>  
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/user_index.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: WHERE code='$testcode', name='$testname', email='$email', redeemed='$testredeemed' - this is not valid syntax

Comment: Why not test your queries before sticking them in your code

Comment: @Strawberry Ok. I wonder if I only need to get the three latter values, assign them to variables based on WHERE code='$testcode'. I'm using PHPadmin so I'm not sure exactly how to set up the command line for that. I guess I should look that up.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is fine for setting up tables, familiarising yourself with the structure of databases, etc., but I really think it's vital to be fairly adept at navigating the command line. It's actually pretty easy - especially if you work with a decent text editor running alongside (FWIW, I use TextPad on Windows).